# SQL join with no common column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Hello I have 3 tables that I need to create a stored procedure to have ClassID as an input and the results will show the ClassName, BookName, ClassType
the problem is each of these columns is in different tables and I don't have common columns between all of them to use JOIN command

my 3 tables structure as follows

- ClassTable got the columns (ClassID, ClassName, CourseID, IsActive)
- BookTable got these columns (BookID, BookName, ClassTypeID, IsActive)
- ClassType Table got these columns (ClassTypeID, ClassType)

I tried to use CROSS JOIN but I felt it was giving me random results
is there any way to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like your class table should either have a ClassType column or a ClassTypeId column. It makes sense that a class would have a type.  Are you sure that you listed all of the columns for the ClassTable?

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk, unfortunately, no, does that mean its not doable?

Comment: Show sample data, input, and output. Show what you tried and explain why the results seemed wrong. This is far too vague as currently written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose that the structure of your tables looks as follows:

```sql
    create table ClassTable(
        ClassID int not null identity(1, 1),
        ClassName nvarchar(255) null,
        CourceID int,
        IsActive bit,
        ClassTypeID int /* I added this column for join with [ClassType] table */
    )

    create table ClassType(
        ClassTypeID int not null identity(1, 1),
        ClassType nvarchar(255)
    )

    create table BookTable(
        BookID int not null identity(1, 1),
        BookName nvarchar(255),
        ClassTypeID int,
        IsActive bit
    )
```

Script to create a stored procedure for displaying  `[ClassName]`, `[BookName]` and `[ClassType]` fields  by passing `ClassID` as parameter, will look like this:

```sql
    use [ NAME_OF_YOUR_DATABASE ]/* this need to define a name of your database */
    go

    set ANSI_NULLS on
    go
    set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on
    go

    create procedure [dbo].[ NAME_YOUR_STORED_PROCEDURE ]/* this need to define a name of your storedproc */
        @ClassID int,

        @ClassName nvarchar(255) output,
        @BookName nvarchar(255) output,
        @ClassType nvarchar(255) output
        
        
    as
    begin

        set NOCOUNT on

        select 
            set @ClassName = classTable.ClassName
            set @BookName = bookTable.BookName,
            set @ClassType = classType.ClassType
            
        from       
            ClassTable as classTable
            inner join ClassType as classType on classType.ClassTypeID = classTable.ClassTypeID
            inner join BookTable as bookTable on bookTable.ClassTypeID = classType.ClassTypeID

        where 
            classTable.ClassID = @ClassID

    end
```

And then, You'll can to call the stored procedure by parameter

```sql
exec [ NAME_YOUR_STORED_PROCEDURE ] 123 /* this need to define value for ClassID as param */
```